# Can I email a note to Trello - like I do in Backpack?

Tags: trello

Can I email a note to Trello - like I do in Backpack? I am just trying to make projects in Trello and the thing that works well, to get a thought out of my head and into a project, is to email that note/thought to Backpack.

Each page in Backpack has it's own unique email so I have to go to Backpack first to grab that unique email address.

I'm thinking there might be a similar action in Trello...maybe?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this would be to use Zapier to [Create a New Trello Card from a GMail Message](https://zapier.com/zapbook/gmail/trello/2057/create-trello-card-from-email/).

*Disclaimer: I'm a Zapier employee, but I actually use this to get ideas dumped into trello to follow up on later.*

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, they're working on a [Google Apps integration](https://trello.com/card/google-apps-integration/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1307). In addition, the feature to create [cards through email](https://trello.com/card/create-cards-via-email/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1171) is "known" by Trello, no details as to when they can implement.

Comment: Implemented in August 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails straight to Trello now with [Emello](http://emelloapp.com). (http://www.emelloapp.com) It allows you to send any email to Trello. You can also pick out and customize email addresses for specific boards and lists. Works from any email client (mobile of desktop)

Comment: Are you affiliated with the service mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Per [FAQ#promotion] please disclose your affiliation with the named service.

Answer (score 0):

This capability has now been added to Trello. http://blog.trello.com/create-cards-via-email/

Basically, you can go to board e-mail settings, copy an address and you're done. You send the notes from your account e-mail.

Note: I'm in no way affiliated with Trello.